# Retrieve static webpage on client cache from dynamic content

Tags: php, cache

I was developing a website on a certain web host and they lost everything. They told me their disks crashed and even the backup are unretrievable. I am mad.

As I was often accessing my website through my personal browser, is there any way I can get the static webpages from my cache?

I managed to find the css, pictures and js files from my local cache, but I would really want to also get back all the texts (content) that I've written.

The webpages were generated dynamically (php) from a database (mysql) so I found no html files containing the text for each of my pages.

Is there a way I can get these texts or any trace of html source for my webpages..?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on which browser you were using. If it was Firefox, then try typing this in address bar: **`about:cache`**. You will be interested in disk cache: **`about:cache?device=disk`**. This will give you an idea of what you can still find in a cache.

Unfortunately this will not work in all browsers.

If you are on Windows, try these free programs:

- [ChromeCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html)
- [MozillaCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html)
- [OperaCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opera_cache_view.html)
- [IECacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ie_cache_viewer.html)

You may also look for browser extensions (at least for Firefox and Chrome) that will allow you to save cached file locally when browsing about:cache pages.